# How do I deploy a database project?

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2010

My project is near completion, about to be rolled out into production. To get the production database into source control before we start SP prep and additional phases, I created a database project (SQL DB 2005). No problems and I think I get everything with the db proj. When I tested the database project by deploying to my local .\SQLEXPRESS I was deluged with warnings similiar to the following:

```
SQL04151: Procedure: [dbo].[spGetSalesData] has an unresolved reference to object [sys].[objects].
```

How do I resolve this? This is my first time using a database project so it could be something minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/7a2803dc-5cce-43ad-96f3-5c886cb93673#f66cbed0-aaac-40e9-8e4b-3f1dca9aef92).

Answer (score 0):

sys.objects can be anything from tables, to stored procedures, to primary keys, to views, and triggers.

It appears that it's referencing some object in the spGetSalesData stored procedure that your local  db doesn't contain.